# Create group over wifi

Tags: android, serversocket, wifip2p

I'm trying to make an application that connects devices over the same WiFi. I'm fairly new to Android development, but I have basic Java knowledge. Now I want to know if my approach is correct?

My approach is as following: I first connect two devices together through WiFiP2P (this part of the code is finished). Next one device creates a SocketServer. That device will send his IP through WiFiP2P to the other device so the devices can now join.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Mind clarifying what you mean? You say you connect two devices, create a SocketServer, which then sends an IP (sending is something a client client does normally??) to the other device that then joins (what?).

Comment: I already thought it would be a lot of jabber. But basically I'm creating a SocketServer. But because the IP is unknown, I thought I would use WiFip2p to transfer the IP of the device that started the server. And I wanted to know if that was the correct approach.

Comment: So you are implementing a form of wireless service discovery?

Comment: Yes, my goal is to create a group over WiFi, which you can join. For a simple WiFi game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding of WiFiP2P is fairly limited, but I'm assuming that it is trying to be what Bluetooth failed to be.

This approach sounds fine. There is even [a page on the offical documentation about it](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd-wifi-direct.html).

My only thought is that you should add protection against malicious users performing spoofing attacks, if that is relevant to your app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I don't think I have to protect my app. Only strings will be send. Besides, it's a family game :P